# GWT: Working with query string

Tags: database, gwt, iframe, query-string

I am working with iframes, .aspx files and of-course GWT.

I have some .aspx files running on windows server. I am accessing it through iFrames from GWT. The problem is i have to send a query from my GWT to windows server i.e., .aspx file. I used the following approach of embedding the query in the url.

```
http://localhost:46703/WebForm1.aspx?Select=emp_id&From=emp_table
```

The concern with this approach is that the security has been compromised. Is there any other workaround for this?

```
Note: Currently working with GWT 2.4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secure the aspx server so that the user's session is required, and validate that the session should have access to the data being retrieved.

Sorry for such a short answer, there are whole books on how to accomplish this.

Also, don't pass the SQL query itself as parameters, instead you should have a lookup on the server side that has the query predefined to avoid SQL injection.